# How can I check whether a file that i have open is for reading or writing in c

Tags: c++, c

[image]

I have tried this, which is fine, but I want to check a file that I have opened during runtime whether it is open for read or write.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read [why not upload images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: As you opened the file during runtime, you should be able to keep track of it. Like "how much memory did I allocate?" the answer is "the amount that you requested" (except when failure).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no standard way to check the mode of opened file in C. You can keep track of the mode by using a variable:

```
const char* mode = "w";
FILE* fp = fopen("file", mode);
if (mode[0] == 'r')
    ; // read mode
else
    ; // write mode
```

There may be implementation defined non-standard ways of getting the open mode. For example, POSIX standard specifies `fcntl` function, which can be used to get the flags associated with a file descriptor. If you've used a C standard function that returns a `FILE*`, then you can use the POSIX function `fileno` to get the associated descriptor.